# Как создать расширяющий метод для заполнения массива C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу сделать заполнение массива при помощи расширяющего метода, но ничего не получается. Я имею ввиду, что программа не падает при вызове метода, но он ничего не делает.

Вот код расширяющего метода:

```
public static class ExtencionIntArrayMethods
{
    public static void Fill(this int[] array, int quantity, int from, int to) =>
        array = Enumerable
            .Repeat(0, quantity)
            .Select(x => Utils.GetRand(from, to))
            .ToArray();
} // ExtendedIntArrayMethods.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим, ваш изначальный массив (объект) - это дом. Переменная - это, по сути, бумажка с адресом дома. То есть вот тут

```
var array = new int[10];
```

вы

1. Создаете дом, где поселяется и живет массив
2. создаете бумажку (переменная array)
3. пишете на этой бумажке адрес дома.

После, когда вы вызывете какую то функцию

```
Fill(int[] copyOfArrayVariable)
{
    ...  
}

Fill(array)
```

вы

1. Берете вторую бумажку copyOfArrayVariable
2. Копируете туда адрес вашего массива
3. Отправляете эту новую бумажку почтой россии в вашу функцию

Далее, когда вы делаете следующее в фунцкции

```
Fill(int[] copyOfArrayVariable)
{
    ...  
    copyOfArrayVariable = new int[1000];
}
```

вы

1. Создаете второй дом со вторым массивом
2. Берете эту копию бумажки с адресом
3. Стираете старый адрес с копии и пишете туда новый адрес.

При этом ваш изначальный массив не меняется, он живет все там же. Ваша изначальная бумажка с адресом тоже не меняется, она также указывает на первый массив. Все, что происходит, - это просто кто то что то делает с копией бумажки, которая была выслана в функцию и там и останется.

Comment: А, допустим, гномики в этом доме есть?

Comment: это же очевидно, иначе кто будет сообщать о проблемах с программой? :D

Comment: Я знаю, как это работает, но не думал, что это относится к массивам, т.к. это ссылочный тип данных. Я имею ввиду то, что если ту же самую манипуляцию мы проделаем при помощи типизированного списка (List<int>), то все элементы, в отличие от массива, поменяются. Вот это и является для меня тайной. Как я понимаю, оба типа ссылочные, но почему в случае с массивом мы получаем в функцию копию, а в случае со списком работаем по ссылке, я не понимаю.

Comment: @ДанилДзевелюк это относится ко всем ссылочным типам. Переменная в этом случае (бумажка с адресом) - это и есть ссылка. Если вы проделаете то же самое со списком, вы получите точно такой же результат.

Comment: @ДанилДзевелюк `если ту же самую манипуляцию мы проделаем при помощи типизированного списка (List<int>), то все элементы, в отличие от массива, поменяются` это неверно. Покажите код, где у вас список поменяется.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я что-то очень затупил. Просто в моём случае я новой переменной присваивал новый массив, соответственно, старый не менялся. Если бы я работал именно с объектом, то бишь не присваивал переменной ссылку на новый массив, а менял элементы в самом объекте, то тогда всё бы работало. Благодарю.

Comment: @ДанилДзевелюк хорошо, что все прояснилось.

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаете ссылку на объект в функцию, а внутри функции присваиваете этой переменной другое значение. Это сработает только с `ref`/`out` параметром, но тогда extension-метод применить не получится.

```
public static class IntArrayMethods
{
  public static void Fill(out int[] array, int quantity, int from, int to) =>
    array = Enumerable
        .Repeat(0, quantity)
        .Select(x => Utils.GetRand(from, to))
        .ToArray();
}

int[] arr;
IntArrayMethods.Fill(out arr, 10, 1, 5);
```

Так как массив в функции не используется, его можно просто возвращать:

```
public static class IntArrayUtils
{
  public static int[] Fill(int quantity, int from, int to) =>
    Enumerable.Repeat(0, quantity).Select(x => Utils.GetRand(from, to)).ToArray();
}

int[] arr = IntArrayUtils.Fill(10, 1, 5);
```

Comment: У меня сейчас немного другой вопрос. Я же передаю в функцию именно ссылку, а не копию объекта. Так почему же сам объект не меняется, когда я меняю его в функции?

Comment: @ДанилДзевелюк Вопрос именно тот, на какой ответ. Вы не *меняете* объект. Вы создаете совершенно новый объект, не имеющий  к старому объекту никакого отношения.

Comment: Можно внутри метода фором присваивать элементы нового массива по индексам старого. И, как вариант, новый вообще не создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен именно метод расширения, то может не создавать новый массив, а тупо заполнять тот, ссылку на который передаете в метод? Такой метод расширения работает

```
    public static void Fill(this int[] array, int from, int to)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            array[i] = Utils.GetRand(from, to);
    }
```

Параметр `quantity` в такой редакции лишний, т. к. вы не сможете поменять длину массива без создания нового массива.