# В список добавляется копия или ссылка

Tags: c#, .net

Год уже ковыряюсь в c#, и только сейчас задумался над вопросом, он меня поставил в большой ступор. Условно, есть пустой список и объект. В список добавляем объект, далее объект ссылаем на новый объект. Раньше считал, что и элемент списка будет изменен. Ведь это всё ссылки. Но значение в списке остается старым, из старой ссылки. Как объяснить это с помощью теории?

````
string firstResult = "";
string secondResult = "";

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

Person p = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "A"};
persons.Add(p);

firstResult = $"result: {persons[0].Name}";

// "result: A"
 
p = new Person() {Id = 2, Name = "B"} ;

secondResult = $"result: {persons[0].Name}";

// "result: A" ```
````

Comment: Так это же просто объясняется, разве нет? Внутри списка есть внутренний массив, куда всё добавляется. И считай этот элемент массива имеет ссылку на объект, что тут удивительного. Можно черезчур утрированно рассматривать массив как большое количество независимых переменных...В какой-то момент одна из этих переменных начинает ссылаться на объект....а первоначальная переменная её обрубает

Comment: не бывает старых/новых ссылок, они (ссылки) либо есть, либо их нет, и чего бы вы не делали с объектом (на который ведёт ссылка) - на ссылку это не влияет, и на объект не влияет)

Comment: [почему такое поведение у объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302952/179763)

Answer (score 5):

Вот смотрите:

```
p = new Person()
```

вы создали объект, и его адрес ("квартира 666")записали на листочек (`p`)

```
persons.Add(p);
```

Здесь вы переписали в записную книжку (`persons`) адрес с листочка `p`, теперь в книжке есть запись "квартира 666"

```
p = new Person()
```

На листочкe стёрли старую запись, адрес теперь другой, сделали новую запись ("квартира 777"). Но записная книжка об этом не знает, и в ней по-прежнему записано "квартира 666"

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в переменную вы записываете ссылку. Когда вы закидываете ссылку в список, то по факту, вы просто присваиваете эту ссылку другой переменной. Ну вот чисто для примера, есть класс какой-то

```
public class Class { }
```

И переменные

```
Class a = new Class(); // a = v1
Class b = new Class(); // a = v1, b = v2
```

Что будет далее?

```
a = b // a = v2, b = v2
```

Теперь у нас в `a` и в `b` **хранится** ссылка на один объект. Если я сделаю вот так:

```
b = new Class(); // a = v2, b = v3
```

Тогда у нас `a` до сих пор ссылается на объект **v2**, а переменная `b` имеет теперь ссылку на **v3**, это логично

> Раньше считал, что и элемент списка будет изменен

Спросить "Почему вы так считали?" будет не уместно, так что просто так не делайте больше и всё будет хорошо. Ссылка есть ссылка, переменная это просто место для хранения. Сами места для хранения сохраняют как бы... **Значимое** значение ссылки, а не саму ссылку... (Только не ругаейтесь за формулировку). В общем, изучите тему указателей в C++, тогда вы всё поймёте

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:** *В список добавляется копия ссылки (в Вашем коде).*

**Развёрнутый ответ (для Вашего кода):**

Вы затёрли адрес (ссылку) на объект в памяти новым адресом (ссылкой) в памяти на новый созданный объект. При добавлении в массив *persons*, добавляется адрес объекта на который ссылается переменная *p*, а не сама переменная *p*, то есть копируется адрес (ссылка) из *p*. По факту у вас получается две разных однотипных переменных *persons[0]* и *p*, ссылающихся на один и тот же объект, но в последствии у переменной *p* Вы меняете адрес объекта, другого объекта.

Объявление переменной просто строкой:

```
Person p;
```

по факту означает, что эта переменная не ссылается ни на какой объект в памяти.

Слово *new* означает, что Вы создаёте новый объект в новом участке памяти, соответственно по новому адресу (ссылке) в памяти. Например, просто напишите следующую строчку:

```
new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "B" };
```

и ошибок не будет и никаких действий Вы над этим объектом совершить тоже не сможете, так как адрес (ссылка) на созданный объект ни какой переменной не присвоена. А в памяти этот объект будет существовать, до тех пор, пока его не удалит сборщик мусора.

В Вашем случае, следующий код будет аналогичным и возможно более понятным:

```
Person p;    
p = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "A" };
p = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "B" };
```

то есть сначала Вы создаёте первый новый объект в памяти и ссылку (адрес) присваиваете переменной *p*, потом создаёте второй новый объект в памяти уже с совсем другим адресом и снова присваиваете той же переменной *p*. А тот адрес, который  был до этого естественно затёрся, исчез. Но сам первый объект из памяти никуда не делся, вы просто потеряли адрес (ссылку) расположения этого объекта в памяти. Позже объекты в памяти без активных ссылок удаляются сборщиком мусора для освобождения памяти.

Но в Вашем коде, ссылка (адрес) на первый объект является активной, так как была добавлена в массив *List persons* под индексом *0*. Хочу заметить, что добавлен (скопирован) именно адрес (ссылка) на объект в памяти из переменной *p*, а не сама переменная *p*, и уж тем более не сам объект.

Чем отличается вот такая запись:

```
persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "C" });
```

По сути ни чем. Компилятор (если образно) преобразует эту короткую запись в следующие строки уже за Вас, можно сказать дописывает, так как программисты очень ленивые и не любят много писать:

```
Person p1;
p1 = new Person();
p1.Id = 3;
p1.Name = "C";
persons.Add(p1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Суть: есть куча, там объекты.
Грубо на пальцах: вы вообще не можете влиять на объекты (за исключением того, что вы можете создать объект). А дальше (почти всегда) оно пускается на "самотёк". В этом и есть смысл кучи как таковой, потому что в таком случае за кучей не нужно следить. Она сама за собой следит, через коллектор.

Но что бы иметь возможность достучаться до объекта - нужна ссылка, и по сути это переменный указатель, а в рамках самоуправляющейся среды дот.нета - это ссылка/референс.

Сделано это для того, что бы объекты можно было перемещать в куче, дефрагментировать кучу, сжимать кучу и так далее. Но реальный физический адрес на объект - меняется, и вам за этим следить не нужно, потому что у вас ссылки. На объекты кучи.

Как только на объект кучи не ведёт ни одна ссылка - объект становится не нужен. Ссылок нет же - тогда вы до объекта не достучитесь, значит объект можно уничтожить. Этим и занимается коллектор. Сколько бы вы не создавали объектов - коллектор за ними следит. И за ссылками на эти объекты тоже следит.

Суть конкретно:

```
object obj0 = new object();
// ссылка obj0, она ссылается на объект в куче

object obj1 = obj0;
// теперь две ссылки ссылаются на один и тот же объект в куче

object.ReferenceEquals(obj0, obj1);
// выведет True, этот метод сравнивает именно ссылки (адреса) на объект
// сами объекты не сравниваются никак, зачем?

object obj2 = new object();
// ещё один объект в куче, теперь их два

object.ReferenceEquals(obj0, obj2);
// выведет False, ссылки (адреса) указывают на разные объекты
object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2);
// выведет False, ссылки (адреса) указывают на разные объекты

// однако же ссылке можно ПЕРЕНАЗНАЧИТЬ объект
// obj0 = obj2;
// obj1 = obj2;
// теперь все три ссылки будут указывать на один и тот же (второй) объект

// однако же на первый объект теперь ссылок нету, это проверит коллектор и
// уничтожит (освободит память), которую занимал первый объект в куче
```

Получается так, что ссылки и объекты чрезвычайно мало связаны. Связь именно только через указание, и никакой иной связи - нет. И не должно быть. Внимательно отслеживайте вашу программу, и тогда всё получится.
Но указание можно ПЕРЕНАЗНАЧИТЬ. Это именно ваш случай и есть.

Ваша программа:

```
string firstResult = "";
string secondResult = "";
// здесь кстати object.ReferenceEquals(firstResult, secondResult) возвратит True
// а почему? ;)

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
// здесь вы замутили внутренний массив ссылок, они все указывают на null
// на самом деле вы ничего не замутили, потому что внутренний массив даже
// не создастся, потому что к нему никто не обращался (пока ещё нет)

Person p = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "A"};
// здесь вы замутили объект в куче, и ссылку "p" на этот объект
// ссылка есть - объект "живёт"
persons.Add(p);
// вы добавили ссылку в массив ссылок
// здесь и создаётся массив ссылок, и в этот массив помещается ссылка "p"
// теперь persons[0] указывает на объект с Name = "А"

firstResult = $"result: {persons[0].Name}";
// persons[0] - это ссылка, она не null

// "result: A"

p = new Person() {Id = 2, Name = "B"};
// здесь вы создаёте второй объект, помещаете его в кучу, но на этот объект
// ссылается "p", вы "p" ПЕРЕНАЗНАЧИЛИ на новый объект с Name = "В"

secondResult = $"result: {persons[0].Name}";
// здесь вы опять запросили ссылку (она добавлена в массив), ссылка вам
// возвращается, и она как вела так и ведёт на тот самый
// первый объект с Name = "А", который вы добавляли в массив изначально
// именно потому и будет опять
// "result: A"
```

Что бы понять именно равенство ссылок (не объектов, а ссылок на них) - выше приведены примеры с object.ReferenceEquals(), и оно приведено не просто так. Поэкспериментируйте с этим.

Comment: Советую вам научиться писать ответы без воды, при чём здесь `ReferenceEquals` вообще? Автор интересуется как это работает, а не как сравныить 2 ссылки. Смысл ему от сравнивания, если он не знает, что такое ссылка? В ответе много лишнего. Что такое "куча"? _за кучей не нужно следить_ - а сборку мусора зачем приплели? Дефрагментации какие-то. Мне кажется, что вопрос был не в этом. Плохой ответ, не по уровню вопроса. Ответ должен быть понятным и лакончиным, и отвечать на вопрос в первую очередь, а всё остальное потом.

Comment: ReferenceEquals притом, что сравнивает ссылки. И без этого автор в ссылках не разберётся. И метода сравнивающего "листочки" в рантайме нету.