# Различия между ссылочными типами данных string и array (C#)

Tags: c#, массивы, типы-данных, адрес

Возможно это глупый вопрос но до меня так и не доходит в чем же тут дело.
У меня есть вот такой код:

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    int[] array = new int[1]{777};
    Change(array);
    Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
    string text = "Etot text ne izmenitsya";
    Change(text);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
  }
  
  static void Change(int[] array)
  {
      array[0] = 666;
  }
  
  static void Change(string text)
  {
      text = "Change this";
  }
}
```

Я пытаюсь понять как работают ссылочные и значимые типы данных. В моем случае я использую массив и строку и как я понимаю оба обьекта относятся к ссылочным типам данных, однако когда я передаю значения массива и меняю их в методе они меняют значение в куче (куда по логике попадают все данные ссылочных типов), а когда передаю строку и меняю ее в методе - изменений нет.
Я понимаю что наверное я выгляжу крайне глупо, но я не понимаю как так происходит. Может ли кто обьяснить почему так?

Comment: [Раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302952/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1090274/179763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете немного разные вещи:

```
array[0] = 666;
```

Здесь вы меняете значение по индексу 0 по скопированной в стек вызванного метода ссылке на лежащий в куче массив массив. Элемент массива в куче меняется, и вы видите изменения глобально.

```
text = "Change this";
```

Здесь вы переприсваиваете скопированную в стек вызванного метода ссылку. Если вы будете дальше внутри этого метода работать с `text`, то вы будете работать с новой ссылкой. Глобально же изменений никаких не будет, `text` из `Main` по-прежнему хранит ссылку на `"Etot text ne izmenitsya"`, изменилась только ссылка `text` внутри кадра стека `Change`.

Comment: Хм. А почему конструкция:
```
text = "Change this";
```
Переприсваивает ссылку? Я просто хотел изменить данные самым обычным присваиванием, неужели без ref не обойтись? Немного не понимаю в чем тогда смысл ссылочных типов данных и почему они по разному взаимодействуют с методами. Как будто здесь нет никакого правила просто нужно запомнить что вот со строками так а с массивами по другому =(

Comment: ```string text = "Text.";``` Здесь text - ссылка на кадре стека, хранящая адрес объекта System.String, лежащего в куче, и грубо представляющего собой массив символов. Если делается ```text = "Other text.";```, то в ссылку text присваивается адрес другого объекта - массива символов из кучи, хранящего другой текст. Оригинальный массив "Text." при этом никак не затронут, он в куче как лежал, так и лежит.

Comment: А вообще вы взяли плохой пример для изучения ссылочности, потому что string - immutable тип, и у него нельзя изменить экземпляр после его создания. Создайте какой-то свой изменяемый класс и разберитесь с разницей между изменением ссылки на объект и объекта через ссылку. Ключевое слово ref это вообще третий отдельный случай, он не связан с ссылочными типами и типами значений, он про передачу в стеке переменных по значению (создается независимая копия) или по ссылке (происходит работа с оригинальной переменной).